# How to merge multiple HTML files into one master HTML file

Tags: html

Let's say I have the following HTML files:

**header.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="headerstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Page Header</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**body.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="body.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>Page Body</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to take these two files and make a master file that would look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="headerstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="body.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Page Header</div>
    <span>Page Body</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I go about merging them into one HTML file in Java, maybe using Java (JSoup) or JQuery?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: have you used `<frameset></frameset>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do by `<Frameset>` Hope you get your needs

```
<frameset cols="50%,*">
  <frameset rows="50%,*">
      <frame src="frame_a.htm">
      <frame src="frame_c.htm">
  </frameset>
  <frame src="frame_b.htm">
</frameset>
```